# How to update a String user input in dart CheckUser = stdin.readLineSync(); during a while loop

Tags: string, dart, user-input

I am trying to make a function that checks if the persons username is correct to whats saved on file.

```
import 'dart:io';

 var Username = "Marcus";
 var Password = "Fenix";

 String CheckUser = "";
 String CheckPass = "";


void main() {

 print("Hello! please enter your username:\n");
 String? CheckUser = stdin.readLineSync();

 print("Please enter your password:\n");
 String? CheckPass = stdin.readLineSync();

 UserCheck();
 PassCheck();



}

void UserCheck() {
while (CheckUser != Username){

print("The username you provided is incorrect. Please type the username again.\n");
CheckUser = stdin.readLineSync();
  }

}
```

The error is when the program asks for the correct username, it gets stuck within the loop and doesn't update CheckUser to the correct username to exit the loop. I took out the 'String?' for the while loop so that it would update the variable but now there is an error that says "A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.

I've done something similar to this with another program but with the user input asking for an integer:

```
int? Variable = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
```

and by removing the 'int?' within the while loop the variable was able to update correctly and exit the loop.

Is there something in dart that allows me to achieve this with the input being a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong:

1. You have global `CheckUser` and `CheckPass` variables, but your `main` function has local variables with the same names.  The local variables [*shadow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global ones.  Consequently, `main` sets the local variables, not the global variables, ultimately doing nothing since the `UserCheck` function (and presumably the `PassCheck` function, which isn't shown), examines the value of the global version.
2. In the `UserCheck` function, `CheckUser = stdin.readLineSync();` cannot work because `stdin.readLineSync()` returns a `String?`, but the global `CheckUser` is declared as a non-nullable `String`.
3. **Fundamentally the proper way to use `stdin.readLineSync()` is to check if it returns `null`**.  That's *why* it returns a nullable type! `stdin.readLineSync()` returns `null` if it reaches EOF (with no other input).  If you check if a local variable is `null`, it will automatically by type-promoted to a non-nullable type if it isn't `null`.  Typically then you'd do:

   ```dart
   var line = stdin.readLineSync();
   if (line != null) {
     // Do something with the `line` value.
   }
   ```

In your case, you could do:

```dart
void UserCheck() {
  while (CheckUser != Username){
    print("The username you provided is incorrect. Please type the username again.\n");
    var line = stdin.readLineSync();
    if (line == null) {
      exit(1);
    }
    CheckUser = line;
  }
}
```

Note that this doesn't address the variable shadowing problem, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I seemed to have fixed the shadow variable problem, however I'm having problems with the while loop:

void UserCheck(LineUser, Username) {
  var a = true;
  while (a = true){
    if (LineUser != Username || LineUser == null){
    
      print("The username you provided is incorrect. Please type the username again.\n");
      LineUser = stdin.readLineSync();
    
    if (LineUser == Username){
      print("Correct Username!");
      a = false;
   }
  }
 }
}
prints "Correct Username!" but the loop stalls(not exiting the program).
exit(1); seems to stop the entire program.

Comment: @Nenga `while (a = true)`  *assigns* `true` to `a`.  To test for equality, use `==`.  Since `a` is already a `bool`, even better would be to not perform an explicit equality check at all: `while (a)`.

Comment: Ah, I must've missed that while typing it. Thank you very much! :)